# Can you suggest any resources with WP7 map application examples?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

Can't find any good examples with bing map application for windows phone 7. Do you know any?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

have you looked at the sample maps application provided by Microsoft? its part of their [code samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for WP7

Comment: If you will see this map example, you will learn how to change zoom level. Great solution.